# How to hide a part of div when appending it to dom

Tags: jquery, css

normally when i want to hide a part a div,i will do

```
postion:absolute;
left:-1000px;
```

this works,and the scroll bar wont show. but when i try to append a div using the same style,
the scroll bar shows up,any idea why and how to fix it.

by the way i tryed overflow:hidden, it wont work.

here is the code

```
#container{
width: 85%;
height: 900px;
margin: 0px auto;
overflow: hidden;
/*background-color: green;*/
```

}

```
.work_area{
width: 1090px;
height: 700px;
margin: 10px 0px;
/*padding-top: 200px;*/
background-color: #FFF;
box-shadow:0px 0px 13px #666;
/*border-radius: 8px;*/
position: absolute;
right:-1020px;
```

}

```
   $('#container').append("<div id='realapp_wrapper' class='work_area'></div>")
```

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle @ www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

try: 
overflow:hidden;
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: could you show me your full part of code? And your browser also.

Comment: Add: position: relative; to container.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to have a css class for this

```
.hidden {display: none}
```

or

```
.hidden {visibility: hidden}
```

Then, append the div assigning the hidden class to it.
When you need to show the div, simply remove the class from it.

Comment: i just want to hide a part of the div

Comment: Then assign the class to this part. Lets say you have a P inside the div, just assign the hidden class to the P

Comment: Ok, I see the code now. if want to hide .work_area  drop the right:-1020px; and give .work_area a .hidden class (any element can have several classes at the same time. When you want to show it, take of the hidden class, when you want to hide it again, put the hidden back (with js)

Comment: yes but the menu is no there when the page loaded,i need it to be appended after

Comment: you can append it at any time with js as long as the style exists in the css. take a look at this side menu (in red) animations aside, this is done only by put or take out a class http://www.nodari.com.ar/herramientas/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in jquery:

```
$('.slider').appendTo('body');
$('.slider').css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "left" : "-1000px"
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `position: relative` to `#container`